# FMOD_Result result, what does it do

Tags: c++, fmod

Trying to learn FMOD for a school project.

Copied straight from documentation:

```
FMOD_RESULT result;
FMOD::System *system;
result = FMOD::System_Create(&system);      // Create the main system object.
if (result != FMOD_OK)
{
    printf("FMOD error! (%d) %s\n", result, FMOD_ErrorString(result));
    exit(-1);
}
result = system->init(100, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0);    // Initialize FMOD.
if (result != FMOD_OK)
{
    printf("FMOD error! (%d) %s\n", result, FMOD_ErrorString(result));
    exit(-1);
}
```

What does the first line FMOD_RESULT result mean? I found the page in the documentation but it made absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 0):

`FMOD_RESULT` is an typedef for `enum`, what makes `FMOD_RESULT result;` line a variable declaration. You can see what values it can be assigned by checking the `fmod.h` header file.

All the `FMOD` functions return `FMOD_RESULT` value, so that you can check if the function succeeded or what was the error.